# perl to compare three files based on column and extract specific column

Tags: perl

File 1 :

col1 col2 col3 col4 ..... col 15

File 2 :

col1 col2 col3 col4 ..... col 15

File 3 :

col1 col2 col3 col4 ..... col 15
Each column of the files has data.

I need to compare first four column of the three files and output the common from the files 3 along with the file 1 col5.

output :

File 3(col1 col2 col3 col4 ..... col 15)+File 1(col5)

My code :

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $file1 = $ARGV[0];
    my $file2 = $ARGV[1];
    my $file3 = $ARGV[2];

    if($file1 eq "" || $file2 eq "" || $file3 eq "")
    {
             print "Incomplete parameters!\n";
             exit;
    }

    open(FILE1, $file1);
    open(FILE2, $file2);
    open(FILE3, $file3);
    open my $f, '>', "output.txt" or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!";

    my @arr1=<FILE1>;
    my @arr2=<FILE2>;
    my @arr3=<FILE3>;
    close FILE1;
    close FILE2;
    close FILE3;
    my %chash;
    for (@arr1)
    {
            chomp;
            my($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4,$col5,$rest)=split(/\t/);
            my $ckey="$col1$col2$col3$col4";
            $chash{$ckey}=1;
    }

    for (@arr2)
    {
            chomp;
            my($hit1,$hit2,$hit3,$hit4,$hit5,$rest)=split(/\t/);
            my $ckey="$hit1$hit2$hit3$hit4";
            $chash{$ckey}++;
    }
    for (@arr3)
    {
            chomp;
            my($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4,$rest)=split(/\t/);
            my $ckey="$val1$val2$val3$val4";
            $chash{$ckey}++;
            if($chash{$ckey} == 3)
            {
                    # this key has been seen in both previous files
                    print $f "$_\n";
            }
    }
```

This code just give the common lines. Any body help me to extract the file 1 col5 along with the File 3 common line.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you reached print statement, $col5 value is out of scope. So process the files in reverse order so that $col5 is in scope when print statement is used.

```
for (@arr3)
{
    chomp;
    my($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4,$rest)=split(/\t/);
    my $ckey="$val1$val2$val3$val4";
    $chash{$ckey} =1;
}
for (@arr2)
{
    chomp;
    my($hit1,$hit2,$hit3,$hit4,$rest)=split(/\t/); # you don't need $hit5 here
    my $ckey="$hit1$hit2$hit3$hit4";
    $chash{$ckey}++;
}
for (@arr1)
{
    chomp;
    my($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4,$col5,$rest)=split(/\t/);
    my $ckey="$col1$col2$col3$col4";
    $chash{$ckey}++;

    if($chash{$ckey} == 3)
    {
        # this key has been seen in both previous files
        print $f "$_, $col5\n"; # $col5 is in scope
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the column of data present in file 3 along with file 1 col 5.... Because except first four column all others are different in all three files.

Comment: In that case save `$col5` value like this

     `$chash{$ckey}=[1, $col5]`

And increment like this

    `$chash{$ckey}[0]++;`

And check and write like this

     if($chash{$ckey}[0] == 3)
            {
                    # this key has been seen in both previous files
                    print $f "$_ $cahsh{$ckey}[1]\n";
            }

Comment: I am getting the error msg " Can't use string ("3") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ./gms_script.pl line 57" while i print $f "$_ $cahsh{$ckey}[1]\n"; }

Comment: `use strict` prevents having different type in array. Since using `use strict` is a good idea, keep that. Instead save $col5 in a different hash.

Define `my %foohash;` and save $col5 in that hash when you populate $chash. `$chash{$ckey}=1; $foohash{$ckey} = $col5;`
And add that when you print `print $f "$_ $foohash{$ckey}\n";`

Comment: Thank you i got the perfect answer

Comment: I want to improve this code like " i need a output of common in file 1 and 2 but not present in file 3." i used if(( $ahash{$akey} == 2 ) && ( ($bhash{$akey}) != ($ahash{$akey}) == 2)) . ahash for file 1 and 2, bhash for file3. But it doesn't work.